# render the paypal checkout button when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on the paypal express checkout button. The problem is that if the user changes the payment amount, the paypal button renders again. Is there a way to render the paypal button when I click on the button?
I am working with paypal  Checkout.js

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/#

Update: working in web components so all the code is inside renderedcallback()

Answer (score 0):

You have linked to the deprecated checkout.js integration

If you use the current sdk.js integration: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

The reference to `amount:`  can be a function call, for example:

```
amount: getElementById('myamountinput').value
```

Or any other function call of your own you want, to get the value with.

With this solution, the button will not re-render.